# Taiyaki mold with electric coil stove top?

Tags: japanese-cuisine, stove

Examples online of people cooking Taiyaki usually involve a gas range or grill. Would a metal mold work on a electric coil stovetop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have sufficient contact area it can work. This depends on the mold you have.

The one I have is not flat on the outside as it follows the inner shape, so it would have little contact area with an electric coil stove top, while a gas burner would heat it up more evenly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it would be fine.  As the previous poster said, will depend on your taiyaki mold.  Some molds have no border or frame around the actual fish shape, others have it.  Mine happens to have it, and I have cooked on an electric coil range and it’s fine.  If you don’t have the border then it will still cook ok, just slightly uneven heating. One other thing with the borderless molds is being level.  If it is not level then you are more likely to have uneven thickness in the batter or spillover.  So make sure that the batter is mostly set by holding or stabilizing it until the batter is mostly set, add your filling and then pour the other half in.  I would go with a slightly thicker batter as well.